# How to count how many JButtons have been clicked from a 10 x 10 java JButton grid

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

I want to count the number of JButtons that has been clicked on from a 10 x 10 JButton grid.

This is what I am talking about
 [image]

Anyways, I don't know how to count how many JButtons have been clicked. I thought about making 100 JButtons but that seems silly.

Also how do I prevent more than 14 buttons from being clicked?

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener()
{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
             JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
             button.setEnabled( false );

        }
};

    for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
    {
       for(int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
       {
               button = new JButton();
               button.addActionListener( al );
               panel_1.add(button);
       }
    }
```

This is my forLoops for making 100 buttons and giving each of them an actionListener so when a JButton is clicked, it becomes unclickable.

```
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener()
    {
        int clicked = 0;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            button = (JButton)e.getSource();

             if(clicked != 14)
             {
                 clicked++;
             }
             else

                button = (JButton)e.getSource();
                button.setEnabled( false );

        }
    };

    for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
        {
                button = new JButton();
                button.addActionListener( al );
                panel_1.add(button);

        }
    }
```

I have tried putting in a counter but it is obviously not correct. Can I even compared e.getSource() to an int or something?

Comment: you can use a static int that increase according to GUI

Comment: Why don't you just store the state of each button?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ you mean like an int counter?

How would I compare (JButton).e.getSource() to an int counter?

Comment: @gooroo7 what do you mean store the state? Whether the button has been pressed or not? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: not as simple as a *counter*, but the idea is similar, every time you set a button on increase the global counter, when a button is set off you decrease the counter... and you need to check that the counter never exceed 14..

Comment: @i_want_to_die Yes, I mean store whether or not the button has been clicked on or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of clicks you will need to create an int (or long) variable to store them in, and simply add a `++` statement in the `actionPerformed` method:

```
private int buttonClicks = 0; // Or public
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
             if(buttonClicks == 14){
               System.exit(0); // Or a different script
             }else{
             JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
             button.setEnabled( false );
             buttonClicks++; // Record click
             }
        }
```

and if you want to count the number of clicks on a specific button, you will need to create a string array containing all the button names which are found in the constructors:

```
   JButton jbtn = new JButton("Button") // Button is the name
```

and a separate `int` array which will store the clicks. Then you can use a `for` loop to figure out which button was pressed, and increase it's click in the int array.

Consider the following example:

```
aClass(){

    JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Example");
    jfrm.setSize(200, 200);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jfrm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JButton jbtn1 = new JButton("Push");
    JButton jbtn2 = new JButton("Click");
    JButton jbtn3 = new JButton("Press");

    jbtn1.addActionListener(this);
    jbtn2.addActionListener(this);
    jbtn3.addActionListener(this);

    jfrm.add(jbtn1);
    jfrm.add(jbtn2);
    jfrm.add(jbtn3);
}

public static String[] buttonNames = {"Push", "Click", "Press"}; // Put button names in an array
public static int[] buttonClicks = {0, 0, 0}; // Set the clicks to default

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                 for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
                    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals(buttonNames[i])){
                    buttonClicks[i] =  buttonClicks[i] + 1; // Record the clicks. I think you can use buttonClicks[i]++, but I'm not sure
                    }
                 }
            }
```

and anytime you need to access the number of clicks for a specific button, you could use something like the following:

```
public static int getClicks(String buttonName){
       for(int i = 0; i < aClass.buttonNames.length; i++){
           if(buttonName.equals(aClass.buttonNames[i])){
           return aClass.buttonClicks[i];
           }
       }
}
```

and when you call that method, all you have to do is pass the button name to it as a string.
`getClicks("Push");`

Comment: This one works thanks. Also I made the buttons not clickable by using button.disable();

Comment: Your welcome! I'm happy to help =) And `button.disable();` is 100% fine, I only wrote `System.exit(0);` because it's the default statement used when limiting or stopping something =P